# Unable to connect to Azure Storage Emulator from a docker container on the same machine

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I dockerized a .net core 2.2 web api application in Visual Studio 2017 successfully. One part of this application is supposed to store some data to Azure Storage Emulator running on the same machine as VS 2017 is running on. The emulator's configuration looks like below:

```
<services>
   <service name="Blob" url="http://127.0.0.1:10000/"/>
   <service name="Queue" url="http://127.0.0.1:10001/"/>
   <service name="Table" url="http://127.0.0.1:10002/"/>
</services>
```

docker-compose.yml file has the following network definition:

```
build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyWebApi\Dockerfile
      network: host
```

I am able to view the web api's output at **https://127.0.0.1:44315/api/values**

Per my understanding, "host" network configuration did its job by assigning the container's host's IP address to the container which seems good so far. The question is that why the dockerized web app in the container fails to communicate with the emulator in spite of the mentioned configuration. What is missing in this exercise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I remember, the **Azure Storage Emulator** is bound in a local-only network configuration and **Docker for Windows** runs in a **VM** using **Hyper-V**.

I'm afraid the solution would be to use the [microsoft/azure-storage-emulator](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-storage-emulator/) image while developing and point your **API** to it.

**Update**

You could also try and use `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1` as the host in the connection string (this also might let you use the emulator running on your host instead of the container).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply Itay. I installed the docker image that you mentioned and the application is still unable to communicate with the emulator on 127.0.0.1 over port# 10000 or other emulator's ports. The connection string is according to what Microsoft outlined on the docker page. I am able to telnet to the emulator from a windows command prompt but not sure why the application is failing to store in the emulated storage.